# Git: how to find out real changed files in a merge commit?

Tags: git

Conflict filenames are included in auto-generated commit message.

Beside conflict files, if someone makes changes to other files in a merge commit, it is worth noticing the changes to trace why he makes such changes in a merge commit.

If no conflicts, a merge commit should have no real file changes, because each file follows either parent.

What git command line should I type?

I need changed file names only, not diff content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git show --stat` will display a summary of the file names touched by the merge commit itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you `git show` a merge commit, it will show you only that merge commit's changes. Every other change produced by one of the "merged commits" will be shown by `git show`ing that commit.

Comment: I need changed file names only, not diff content.